# Inverse of 'be'?

Tags: phrase-requests, mathematics, subject-verb-inversion, be

<strike>## Context</strike>

(I apologize for the technical programmery context. The root of the question is English though)

I have a static class method `is` that takes in some object and returns whether that object is of that type of class.

Using this method works like this:

`Animal.is(dog)`

Due to technical constraints, I can't swap the subject and object of the sentence to be 'dog is animal' meaning that `animal` must be the subject and `dog` must be the object.

Again, I apologize for all the technical context. The only reason I had to include it is explain why I need an inverse of 'be' in the first place.

Please try to ignore the technical context when answering the question.

### Question

**What word should I use in place of `is` (or any form of be) that acts like the inverse of `is`?**

i.e. what would should I use in the sentence

> "Animal ____ dog".

that holds the same meaning and *truth* as the following?

> "A dog is an animal."

**And to further clarify what I mean by *truth*:**

*"A dog is an animal."* is a fact with some truth that could be tested like *"If a dog is an animal..."*.

Now how can you form an English sentence that states the same fact expect where the subject and object are swapped. e.g. *"An animal ____ a dog."*, *"If an animal ___ a dog..."*.

Is that possible? Does that even make sense?

(I also apologize if I'm not using the correct tag here. Feel free to edit for corrections).

Comment: You have a poor concept of how objects and classes work.  If you use "is" for your operator you will only get more confused.  Try "instanceof" and "classof".

Comment: (In English "is" is generally bidirectional, when context does not imply otherwise.)

Comment: Can you use 'includes'?

Comment: @HotLicks i don't want to talk about the technical context, but the `instanceof` and `classof` operators don't exist here. And I'm aware that `is` is a confusing operator, which is why I'm asking for a better word lol

Comment: @HotLicks has it: `Animal.is(fido)` returns Dog, and `fido instanceof Animal` returns true. But the author Scott Myers says "Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else," slap yourself."

Comment: Maybe `contains` or `isClassOf`

Comment: A dog *is* an animal. A given animal *might be* a dog. When going from generic to specific, you lose the 'single-inheritance' property. Let's call your desired inverse-of-is the operator *F*. Then you want F(animal) to return *dog*. But then F(animal) should legitimately return *cat* as well since "dog is animal" and "cat is animal" are both true.

Comment: The operators don't exist until you create them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about naming software operators, not writing English.

Comment: try  Animal.subsumes(dog)

Comment: Indeed this question has some software terminology (which is a poor fit for ELU), however the core of it is a single-word-request with an example sentence, so I don't think it is off-topic @HotLicks .

Comment: @k1eran - If you don't consider it software terminology then it's still asking for mathematical terminology -- *animal is the superclass of dog*.  English is simply not that precise.

Comment: @mobileink I really like *"subsumes"*. Post that as an answer with a definition and explanation and I'll probably accept it. If you don't in a few days, I might answer my own question with that word.

Comment: @mobileink yeah I'm convinced that *"subsume"* is the best word here. Refer to the definition under the [merriam-webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsume).

*"red, green, and yellow are subsumed under the term “color”"*

Comment: glad you like it. can't post a fuller answer now, but fwiw this is indeed a good English language question insofar as it involves the language of hierarchy.

Comment: for example the problem with "contains" is that it suggests mereology https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mereology

Comment: e.g. my hand contains my fingers, but does not subsume them.

Comment: @mobileink - But hierarchy, in this sense, is the domain of logic, not English.

Comment: @HotLicks which stackexchange would be most appropriate for this question? I'm trying to be a good user here, I promise!

Comment: @mobileink - Logic.  The concept of sets.

Answer (score 1):

A plain English word would be *contains*, so you could write:

```
Animal.contains(dog)
```

A more technical phrase would be *is the class of*, so you would write:

```
Animal.isClassOf(dog)
```

Or you could stick with *is*, and refer back to Bill Clinton -- it depends on what the meaning of *is* is. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general term - though it has a different meaning in C/C++ - you might like "include".  While it's tempting to jump to object-oriented terminology, it's perfectly valid to think of subclasses as members of a set of implementers of a superclass.  That is, to say that dogs and cats are animals is to say they are members of a set of all animals.  Formally:

> Dogs and Cats *are* Animals
>
> Animals *include* Dogs and Cats.

For animals it might sound a bit weird, but it's more natural in context:

> Some car manufacturers include Porsche and Audi.

If you can get away with two words (or jamming two words together) I also like "such as".

> A Dog is an Animal

vs

> Animals such as Dogs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what terms are used in Java; and using their terminology it would be :

> An Animal [class] is *assignment-compatible* with a dog [or a cat] [object].

The Java community have spent an enormous amount time and resources naming their methods, so normally their terminology is a good starting point.

Quoting the relevant [Java API definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)), my emphasis:

> `public boolean isInstance(Object obj)`
>   Determines **if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class**. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator. [...]

---

**NOTE**: This answer was written before question was updated to say: *...  ignore the technical context when answering the question.*

Comment: I'm looking for more of a general term that's not related to a programming language but thank you for the answer